# Weird rotation behavior with hammerjs and threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, hammer.js

I want to rotate an object3D with hammerjs gestures.

Basically the rotation work, but with two issues I can't figure out.

1. The direction of the rotation changes randomly. It turns left. I stop and than move my fingers in the same diction again and suddenly instead of continuing to rotate left its going right. Happens sometimes but not always.
2. Once the rotation is started it only rotates to the same direction, despite me moving my fingers to different directions.

Here is how I handle the rotation:

```
public rotateObject3D (e: HammerInput): void {

    if (rotationEnabled) {
      const translation = new THREE.Vector3();
      const rotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
      const scale = new THREE.Vector3();
      const rotateMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      const deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

      this._myObject.matrix.decompose(translation, rotation, scale);

      this._deltaRot = (e.rotation * 0.01);
      deltaRotationQuaternion.setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
        0,
        this._deltaRot * (Math.PI / 180),
        0,
        'XYZ'
      ));

      deltaRotationQuaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, rotation);

      this._myObject.matrix = rotateMatrix.compose(translation, deltaRotationQuaternion, scale);
    }
  }
```

And this is the call of it:

```
 this._hammerManager.on('rotate', (e) => {
     this._arTools.rotateObject3D(e);
 });
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the *absolute* rotation value, instead of the change in rotation. For instance, consider the following scenario:

- Rotation1: 12°
- Rotation2: 10°
- Rotation3: 5°

By multiplying your quaternions, your object is being rotated to 12°, then 22°, then finally 27°, even though you were turning back towards 0. This is because you're adding the new rotation to the last rotation on each event.

What you should do is save the previous rotation value, and subtract it from the new one, to get the rotation delta:

```
var previousRot = 0;
var newRot = 0;

rotateObject3D(e) {
    newRot = e.rotation - previousRot;

    // You could use newRot for your quaternion calculations
    // but modifying .rotation.y is simpler
    myObject.rotation.y += newRot

    // Save value to be used on next event
    previousRot = newRot;
}
```

With this method, the scenario above will give you the *change* in rotation. Your object will first rotate by +12°, then -2°, then -5°, for a more natural behavior.

Just make sure to reset `previousRot = 0` on HammerJS' `rotateend` event so you don't use the value from previous gestures when a new one begins.